# boost 1.48 and default (1.46) on Precise Pangolin12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, application-development, c++

The Precise release of ubuntu has two libboost-dev packages.  The default is 1.46, but there is also a 1.48.  If I install both, where are the headers and libraries for 1.48 installed?  Are the locations the same if I only install 1.48?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The default is 1.46, but there is also a 1.48.

1.48 is the latest version. 1.46 should upgrade to 1.48, with headers/libraries in the same location. Do you simultaneously need both?

Comment: In some cases, I've seen warnings about conflicting packages, but I didn't see that for the boost packages.  If they are both adding files with the same name to the same location, I figured they should be considered conflicting.

Answer (score 2):

David's question is valid also for my case: it seems that if I upgrade the Boost packages from 1.46 to 1.48 I lose the libogre-dev which depends on 1.46. The "abstract" packages (e.g., libboost-all-dev) are also removed. IMO, that is an indication of an issue with the upgrade path.

I believe an upgrade of the abstract packages to depend on the 1.48 packages instead of 1.46 should cleanly resolve all the issues. Is there such a planned upgrade?